# Conemu getting removed by Norton antivirus as suspcious file.

Tags: conemu

I just formatted my PC, and activated Norton and download conemu from http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html [the Alpha, Installer (32-bit, 64-bit) ].

But, after installing it, and just an hour or so after using it, Norton antivirus blocked and removed Conemu 
[saying it was a behaving suspiciously](http://cdn.imghack.se/images/20c345a9191943d7cfab0d0c19cbb28c.png)  of Norton warning.

I don't know what is wrong. I have a fresh install of Windows 7, 32 bit. And Updated version of Norton antivirus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a false positive. ConeEmu is a reputable app and you should consider this:

1. Check the VirusTotal [scan report here](https://www.virustotal.com/en-gb/file/63af98ecd0152a3cad66200c45f8d4e5bd8fde5d3f3c14b605223f63ec590008/analysis/1405180793/).
2. Report the issue to the author, maybe he can figure what caused Norton to delete ConEmu - check down the page, there's a link and a button named "[Report an Issue](http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html)".

Hope this helps!

Regards, Sam - FossHub

Comment: No need to report issues about false alarms. Antiviral-program user must report false alarm to antiviral-program authors! Related wiki: https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/FalseAlarms